# Is there a way in R to ignore a "." in my data when calculating mean/sd/etc

Tags: r

I have a large data set that I need to calculate mean/std dev/min/ and max on for several columns. The data set uses a "." to denote when a value is missing for a subject. When running the mean or sd function this causes R to return NA . Is there a simple way around this?

my code is just this

```
xCAL<-mean(longdata$CAL)
sdCAL<-sd(longdata$CAL)
minCAL<-min(longdata$CAL)
maxCAL<-max(longdata$CAL)
```

but R will return NA on all these variables. I get the following Error

Warning message:
In mean.default(longdata$CAL) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA

Comment: How did you import the data? Usually there are options to specify what values are missing during import. It's better to fix the problem there than try to clean up afterword.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to convert your data to numeric to be able to do any calculations on it. When you run `as.numeric`, your `.` will be converted to `NA`, which is what R uses for missing values. Then, all of the functions you mention take an argument `na.rm` that can be set to `TRUE` to remove (rm) missing values (na).

If your data is a `factor`, you need to convert it to `character` first to avoid loss of information [as explained in this FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3418128/903061).

Overall, to be safe, try this:

```
longdata$CAL <- as.numeric(as.character(longdata$CAL))
xCAL <- mean(longdata$CAL, na.rm = TRUE)
sdCAL <- sd(longdata$CAL, na.rm = TRUE)
# etc
```

Do note that `na.rm` is a property of the function - it's not magic that works everywhere. If you look at the help pages for `?mean` `?sd`, `?min`, etc., you'll see the `na.rm` argument documented. If you want to remove missing values in general, the `na.omit()` function works well.